# Why the PTS is within pts_of_this_metadata + pixel_exposure_time_ns + rolling_shutter_skew_time_ns

Tags: metadata, google-streetview-publish

Stated by Google's `Camera Motion Metadata` of `VR180`:

> `pts_of_this_metadata`(**t0**) is the exposure start of the first used scanline in a video frame.
>
> `pixel_exposure_time_ns`(**t_pixel**) is the exposure time for a single pixel in nanoseconds.
>
> `rolling_shutter_skew_time_ns`(**△t**) is the delay between the exposure of the first-used scanline and the last-used scanline.
>
> *The PTS of the corresponding frame should be within
> **t0** and **t0 + △t + t_pixel**.*

Let **t_line** be the exposure time for a scanline (which is multiple **t_pixel**).

Why is **t0 + △t + t_pixel**, not **t0 + △t + t_line**?

It seams to me that **t0** to **t0 + △t + t_line** express the whole frame exposure.

Comment: I think the formula from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/camm-spec#data-format) is the CAmera Motion Metadata (CAMM) spec which I think applied to all the 360 camera manufacturers. With that you have to comply with the specifications in the document in order to use the API with your camera.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to comply with the specs and in the meanwhile to understand them. So I'm wondering why is *the PTS within t0 + △t + t_pixel*, not t0 + △t + t_line?